# Is there any library available in Xamarin forms for Token Input view?

Tags: string, view, xamarin.forms, token

I want multiple strings to be added and  deleted in a view. I can achieve this by using native libraries.

Native iOS: CLTokenInputView-Swift-master

Native android: TokenAutoComplete-master

[image]

I want to implement this in Xamarin forms for both iOS and android. Is there any way to achieve this? Or any library files available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like the [TagEntryView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/TagEntryView). It may not do everything you want but it is open-source so maybe you could get the important parts out of there and customize it as you like.

[image: TagEntryView sample]

Comment: Thank you. I will check this